# Store patching output of AWS system manager to S3 prefix using timestamp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to use system manager to patch EC2s. and I use maintainance window to schedule the patching. In task, I want to write output to S3 bucket.
How do I define S3 key prefix with timestamp (or just date since I only plan to schedule patching once every day or week), so that the output is organized in s3 with timestamp folder name,
i.e. today’s output is stored in

```
mys3bucket/<today’s timestamp>/……
```

tomorrow’s output is stored in

```
mys3bucket/<tomorrow’s timestamp>/……
```

how do I set the S3 key prefix in aws console for this purpose? If I cannot, how to set it in AWS CLI or SDK, etc.?

Comment: You can't. You can't do that in the console, CLI or SDK.

Comment: @Mark B 1: Thx. then how to organize my S3 bucket? I just want to organize the output nicely.

Comment: You can't change what it outputs other than a static leading prefix. What type of file organization is it currently outputting?

Comment: currently it goes to: s3:mybucket/testssm1. but do you mean each time before scheduled patching is to happen, I have to update my prefix manually, like testssm2, testssm3?  Here is my sample link of my current file organization. I setup prefix as testssm1, and output is stored this way: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/destisahubucket/testssm1/eff4ab8c-c820-46a3-9d6c-0858172fe919/i-054203c0d24f623ab/awsrunPowerShellScript/0.awsrunPowerShellScript/stdout

Comment: So it's just adding some UUID to the prefix. That's all it is ever going to do for you. So yes, if you really care about adding the date to the prefix you will have to modify it manually before every run. If I were you I would put in a feature request to have it include the date in the S3 prefix like lots of other AWS services do.

Comment: @Mark B. how to add UUID in prefix so I do not need modify it manually before every run? Or, in general, how ppl nicely store a lot of files in s3 so that is it is easy to locate? Thx.

Comment: AWS is adding a UUID to the prefix for you. It's the ID of the execution or something. I don't get what you are asking at this point. People store stuff however they want in S3 when they have control over the entire prefix. You don't have control over the entire prefix being used for SSM logs, so you can't make it any nicer. That's why I said you should put in a feature request.

Comment: @Mark B. I see, for UUID, you mean "eff4ab8c-c820-46a3-9d6c-0858172fe919" in my sample link. That is not user friendly so yeah, I will request a feature for that, Thx.

Comment: Yes that's what a UUID looks like. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier